# Is there anything else like NFS on OEL8?

Tags: linux, filesystems, nfs, rhel7, oel

I want to share a volume from an OEL8 server to two other OEL8 servers and let them read/write to the volume simultaneously. I've been asked to check if there are anymore secure methods/technology in OEL other than an NFS shares. I thought about creating iscsi targets. Are there any new filesystem types that meet my needs ?

Comment: What's wrong with NFS exactly?

Comment: I've been told it uses unsure ports?

Comment: More reading tells me that using NFS V4 uses a more secure port 2049TCP only rather than 111 TCP/UDP

Comment: *I thought about creating iscsi targets.*  If it's not safe to share via NFS on your network, sharing via iscsi is probably worse.